# where to set n_jobs in sklearn pipeline? 'Can't pickle <function <lambda> error'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

trying to figure out how to parallelize my Sklearn pipeline via the n_jobs = -1 parameter with cross-validation ... tried it in a few different steps, but get a pickle error ...

- n_jobs = -1 in FeatureUnion
- n_jobs = -1 in classifier
- n_jobs = -1 in cv k-fold

```
print('The sklearn version => {}'.format(sk.__version__))
The sklearn version => 0.18.1

pipeline = Pipeline([\
        ('unionPipeLines', FeatureUnion(\
            transformer_list = [\
                ('features1', Pipeline([\
                    ('con_features', process_num_data),\
                    ('scales', StandardScaler())\
                ])),\
                ('features2', Pipeline([\
                    ('cat_features', process_cat_data)\
                ])),\
                              ], n_jobs=-1\
                )),\
                ('algs', RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1))])

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4,\
    random_state=11,\
    shuffle=True)

cv_model = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline,\
                              param_distributions=grid,\
                              n_iter=n,\
                              cv=skf,\
                  n_jobs=-1)

cv_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7f5620809158>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

- how can I confirm if the cores are being used?
- where is the correct n_jobs placement so the pipeline utilizing multiple cores during the process?
- why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

- You can confirm the cores are being used:

  Linux: `top` or `ps` commands
  Windows: Task manager
- As far as I know you can only set n_jobs in:

  `pipeline.FeatureUnion(n_jobs=?)`
  Estimators such as `RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-?)` you used

  Beware using `n_jobs` in both a classifier (e.g. `LogisticRegression`) and inside a multiclass classifier strategy (e.g OneVsRestClassifier), for instance, The OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1), n_jobs=-1) would open outer `n_jobs` and the inner `n_jobs` would open some threads.
- Possibly that lambda function is not exported to sub-processes.  I suggest to convert lambda function in regular (def) function or make it available at the subprocess runtime.